# Чтение из текстового файла Pascal

Tags: pascal

Как сделать, чтобы данные вводились не с клавиатуры, а из .txt файла?

```
Program pf;

var 
  x,y,a,b:integer;
begin
  read(x);
  read(y);

  a:=x;
  b:=y;

  if x>y then 
  begin 
    x:=a*b; 
    y:=a+b; 
  end 
  else 
  begin 
    x:=a+b; 
    y:=a*b; 
  end;

  write(x,y);
end.
```

Comment: На самом деле ты можешь читать текст из любого файла, вплоть до расширения .shlasashaposhosse.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь вначале кода(после begin)

```
assign(input, 'input.txt');
reset(input);
assign(output, 'output.txt');
rewrite(output);
```

Не трудно догадаться, что input.txt и output.txt это название файлов ввода и вывода соответственно.

Comment: @АлександрЗасовин То же самое, просто добавьте код который я вам написал после begin. Только ввода у вас там нет)))